# Excel Conditional Formatting Function Syntax using IF / Right

Tags: excel, excel-formula, syntax, conditional-formatting

Newbie Question: Date column in mm/dd/yyyy format, I want to conditional format where 2020 is formatted, but prior years are not.  Tried
=if(right($G:$G,2)="20") , but got no response.
I usually just use the function in an open column, copy down, and sort by that column.
Am I stuck?

Comment: Use `=YEAR(G1)=2020`

Comment: Scott, I wound up using an extra column. When I used the formula, I got a syntax error. COUNTIF and other faves require the quotes ( ="20") and others like year only require the number (=2020).  But I used =YEAR(G$)=2020, because I thought the format had to be tied to the value of each successive field.  Did you only highlight (G1), conditional format, and then copy/paste special/ format-only all the way down?  TIA

Answer (score 0):

Taking a cue from Scott, you can use "=IF(RIGHT(YEAR(G2),2)="20",TRUE,FALSE)".
It worked with "06/02/2020" in G1.

Comment: you only need `=RIGHT(YEAR(G2),2)="20"` part

Comment: How will that have worked for cell G1 when your function references cell G2 ?

Comment: That's a reference formula, replace G2 with the cell where the date is present.